# Secure way to communicate to an API

Tags: android

When it comes to Android development, what is the most secure way to make an app "talk" to an API based on sockets?

Comment: _I think SSL pinning in app and HTTPS  can help you to have a level of security._ You can find details at  [Click Here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#ClientCert)